# How can I split a folder with thousands of images into multiple sub-folders?

Tags: macos, bash, command-line

I have a directory with about 5000 images and I'd like to split/move it in to 50 folders (which will need to be created) with 100 images each.

Is there a way to do this using terminal?

I'm running OS X.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`i=0; for f in *; do d=dir_$(printf %03d $((i/100+1))); mkdir -p $d; mv "$f" $d; let i++; done`

Answer (score 4):

awk one-liner can do that. Consider this awk command:

```
find . -name "*.JPG" | awk '!(++cnt%100) {"mkdir sub_" ++d|getline}'
```

Run it inside the folder with 5000 images. This will create 50 folders with the names sub_1, sub_2...sub_50.

**Also to move files into these newly created directories:**

```
find . -type f | awk '{
   a[++cnt] = $0
}
cnt==100 {
   subd = "sub_" ++d;
   system("mkdir " subd);
   for (f in a)
      system("mv " a[f] " " subd);
   cnt=0
}'
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting the errors find: -name: requires additional arguments

Comment: Thanks for continuing to help but it seems to not be selecting the correct name. I am seeing this *** error mv: rename ./2012-09-10 to sub_2/2012-09-10: No such file or directory *** the filenames are IMG_2789.JPG for example

Comment: Do you have all the images with `.JPG` extension?